# Why I remember a wrong sense of the word "moron"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

I thought that the word "moron" means a very smart person (a genius), but my English teacher has said it means the opposite (an idiot) and it was confirmed by lexicons.

Where did I get this incorrect definition?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not a lot we can do to help you find out why you think that *moron* means its opposite.

Comment: Maybe because it sounds like "more on", causing a mental trigger for "switched on". But at the end you are in control of what you want the words to mean to you, maybe it is even better to have percieve negatory words as good, that way you become an uninsultable ( is there a word for someone who is impervious to insults?).

Comment: Maybe you're a genius!  Assuming I remember what *that* word means...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you heard someone use the *moron* in a context when *genius* was used sarcastically and thought that the person was being told he/she was highly intelligent.

> Good job, genius!
>   Yeah, what a moron!

Comment: This seems likely, many people seem not to get sarcasm and would literally interpret it.